# does Cloudera run with cluster of machine-with Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cloud, cloudera, amazon-emr

I want to ask about "Cloudera" to run Hadoop MapReduce.

Does the cloudera support to run the application over cluster of machine?
What does cloudera actually over, when I use it with Virtual Machine to run the Hadoop MapReduce application?

If Cloudera doesn't support to run over cluster of machine? How can I run Hadoop app in cluster of machine?

I really confused about that:(

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to run a MapReduce application over a cluster of machines that has Cloudera's distribution of Hadoop?

Comment: yes i want run MapReduce application over a cluster of machines. But I don't know does cloudera suppurt that?

Comment: Yes, Cloudera's Distribution supports that.

Comment: that's mean I can run MapReduce app using my computer and cloudera can run it over cluster of machines? Sorry for many questions.

Comment: Cloudera's Hadoop distribution CDH runs on large clusters of machines.  If you configure your laptop as a gateway, you can run your MapReduce apps on the CDH cluster.